# TextArea backup to it's previous value by itself, with example

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I almost lost my mind because of a strange behavior of the **textarea**, it was even hard to replicate for a demo, but fortunately using `outerHTML` property triggers it as well.

On the example: click on change first then on the test button, you will see that the **textarea** back up to its *original value*. If you check it dom before clicking test you will find the old *value persisting*, why does this happen and how to solve it? 
Thank you.

```js
function changevalue(){
 var text=document.getElementById("text");
  text.value="New Text";
}
function testing(){
 var text=document.getElementById("text");
  document.body.innerHTML+="<br>"+(text.outerHTML);
  document.body.innerHTML+="<br>"+(text.value); 
}
```

```html
<form name='test'>
<textarea id='text' name="content">Old Text</textarea>
</form>
<button onclick='changevalue()' >
change
</button>
<button onclick='testing()' >
test
</button>
```

I can solve this problem by giving .innerHTML as well as .value. the same value. But is there another elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls have a [*defaultValue* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) that is their initial (default) value specified in the source HTML. The value will always revert to the *defualtValue* when the form is reset.

The *innerHTML* and *outerHTML* properties reflect the *defaultValue*, not the current value (there's probably something in the [HTML fragment serialisation algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/serializing-html-fragments.html) that covers it).

In the following, you can change the value of the text area to whatever you like, the *defaultValue* will stay the same.

You can change the *defaultValue* by assigning a new value to it. So if you copy a form control using *outerHTML* and want the *defaultValue* to be different to the element you're copying, you need to explicitly set it.

The [*cloneNode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method (which I think is a better choice than *outerHTML*) has the same behaviour.

```js
function showStuff(el) {
  let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  let br = document.createElement('br');
  [['Value property: ', el.value],
   ['Value attribute: ', el.getAttribute('value')],
   ['Default value: ', el.defaultValue],
   ['outerHTML: ', el.outerHTML]
  ].forEach(props => {
    frag.appendChild(span.cloneNode()).textContent = props.join(' ');
    frag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  });
  let t = document.getElementById('elData');
  t.innerHTML = '';
  t.appendChild(frag);  
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Textarea
      <td><textarea name="ta0">Initial value</textarea>
    <tr>
      <td>Show props and atts
      <td><button onclick="showStuff(this.form.ta0)">Show stuff</button>
    <tr>
      <td id="elData" colspan="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Reset the form
      <td><input type="reset">
    <tr>
      <td>Set defaultValue<br>
          <input name="newValue0">
      <td><button onclick="this.form.ta0.defaultValue = this.form.newValue0.value">Change default value to this</button>
    <tr>
      <td>Set value via setAttribute(value)<br>
          <input name="newValue1">
      <td><button onclick="this.form.ta0.setAttribute('value', this.form.newValue1.value)">Change value attribute to this</button>

    <tr>
      <td>Clone textarea
      <td><button onclick="
        let ta1 = this.form.ta0.cloneNode(true);
        ta1.name = ta1.name + this.form.elements.length;
        form.appendChild(ta1);
      ">Clone text area</button>
  </table>
</form>
```

#### defaultValue

According to the HTML spec, the [*defualtValue*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/forms.html#dom-input-defaultvalue) must reflect the [*value content attribute*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/forms.html#attr-input-value). For most form controls, the value attribute is explicit, e.g. `<input value="foo">`. However, for textarea elements, the value content attribute is inferred by the initial value in the HTML, e.g. `<textarea>foo</textarea>`.

The DOM value property (`input.value`) will reflect the current value of the control, however the value attribute (`input.getAttribute('value')`) will reflect the value attribute in the HTML (unless it is changed using *setAttribute*).

Textarea elements didn't have a value attribute historically, so while it's supported through *get/setAttribute*, it's essentially meaningless as it's not used for anything (i.e. either *value* or *defaultValue*). Setting it causes it to appear in the *outerHTML*, but it has no effect on the *value* or *defaultValue* properties.

The serialisation algorithm requires copying content attributes (i.e. those in the source HTML or as modified by setAttribute), not DOM properties, so where the two differ, it's the content attribute that is used. E.g. for an input element:

```
<input name="userID" value="1234">
```

it doesn't matter what the value is changed to via the UI, or using the DOM value property (e.g. `form.userID = '5678'`), the *defaultValue* will remain as "1234". That can be changed by setting the *defaultValue* property, using *setAttribute* won't change it.

The fractured relationship between DOM properties and HTML attributes is historic and has largely been fixed so that they reflect each other, but oddities still remain.

Comment: I used outerHTML just to trigger the behaviour, in my original code, I only work with the value property and for some reason, it back up to its default value. Thank you for your help.